# Parsing xml into a regex value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"         xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
     <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http:///version1/IItemSaleService     /NewCartForTransactionsResponse</a:Action>
      <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="7ccc7b80-b4e8-4fd2-ae61-625b06870191">5b379c02-9288-4e5a-a993-076bf575e5dc</ActivityId>
 </s:Header>
 <s:Body>
 <NewCartForTransactionsResponse xmlns="sservice/itemsale/version1">
<NewCartForTransactionsResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ActionCodes/>
<Cart>
    <BarCodeData>22100245107700005684000000002610153</BarCodeData>
    <CartId>
        <HashBasedMessageAuthenticationCode>42</HashBasedMessageAuthenticationCode>
        <ID>1012451-77-5684</ID>
      ....
</s:Envelope>
```

And I want to get the value of the  node 
    (1012451-77-5684).

Using

```
//ID[0]/text()
```

does not work.

Any tips?

Comment: That's XPath, not a regex. What language are you using? Can you show the code that is extracting the value?

Comment: [Well Regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML/XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: I am using Scala (Gatling stress tool) like this:

.check(xpath("//ID[0]/text()").find.saveAs("id"))

Comment: Ok, Uchiha, but what can I then use to obtain the value of the node <ID> ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanx, it is working Ninja10!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [XPath local-name](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-local-name-example/)

//*[local-name()='ID']

Comment: You need deal with namespace.

Answer (score 0):

How this works, what was final syntax that works?

You use...
.check(xpath("///text()").find.saveAs("id"))

instead of ...
.check(xpath("//ID[0]/text()").find.saveAs("id"))

Comment: Is this a question/comment or answer?